# Django: relation does not exist

Tags: django, database-migration, django-errors

I have pulled myproject updates from bitbucket and tried following commands  'python3 manage.py makemigrations', 'python3 manage.py migrate vehicle', 'python3 manage.py migrate'. But I am getting the following error. vehicle app is new and some of its models use foreign keys from other apps which were migrated before and are in database. I tried different ways, but cannot find the solution. I am using django-1.7.4 I appreciate any advice.

```
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)                                                                                            
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import                                                                                           
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load                                                                                        
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked                                                                               
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked                                                                                        
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module                                                                                  
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed                                                                             
  File "/apps/project/beta/apps/site/admin.py", line 7, in <module>                                                                                         
    from .forms import MenuSubItemAdminForm, MenuChildrenAdminForm                                                                                         
  File "/apps/project/beta/apps/site/forms.py", line 18, in <module>                                                                                        
    class AdvancedVehicleSearchForm(forms.Form):                                                                                                           
  File "/apps/project/beta/apps/site/forms.py", line 24, in AdvancedVehicleSearchForm                                                                       
    make_choices = [(make.id, '{} ({})'.format(make.name, make.stock_count)) for make in Make.objects.get_public().filter(stock_count__gt=0)]              
  File "/apps/project/.virtualenvs/beta/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 141, in __iter__                                       
    self._fetch_all()                                                                                                                                      
  File "/apps/project/.virtualenvs/beta/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 966, in _fetch_all                                     
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())                                                                                                             
  File "/apps/project/.virtualenvs/beta/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 265, in iterator                                       
    for row in compiler.results_iter():                                                                                                                    
  File "/apps/project/.virtualenvs/beta/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 700, in results_iter                            
    for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):                                                                                                                   
  File "/apps/project/.virtualenvs/beta/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 786, in execute_sql                             
    cursor.execute(sql, params)                                                                                                                            
  File "/apps/project/.virtualenvs/beta/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 81, in execute                                       
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)                                                                                            
  File "/apps/project/.virtualenvs/beta/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute                                       
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)                                                                                                                
  File "/apps/project/.virtualenvs/beta/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__                                               
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)                                                                                                      
  File "/apps/project/.virtualenvs/beta/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 658, in reraise                                              
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)                                                                                                                         
  File "/apps/project/.virtualenvs/beta/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute                                       
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)                                                                                                                
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "vehicle_make" does not exist                                                                                   
LINE 1: ..."."country_id", "vehicle_make"."stock_count" FROM "vehicle_m...
```

vehicle app, make model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.text import slugify
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

from apps.location.models import Country
from project.abstract_classes import BaseModel, BaseManager
from .constants import FUEL_CHOICES, GEARBOX_GROUP_CHOICES, VEHICLE_TYPE_CHOICES

# Create your models here.
class Make(BaseModel):
    name = models.CharField(_('name'), max_length=50, unique=True, db_index=True)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                    null=True, related_name='makes')
    stock_count = models.PositiveIntegerField(_("Stock count"), default=0)

    objects = BaseManager()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['country', 'name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name      

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('vehicles-stock-by-make', kwargs={'make': slugify(self.name)})
```

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'easy_thumbnails',
    'adminsortable',

    'apps.location',    
    'apps.vehicle',     
)
```

Comment: please give us your `models.py`  and `INSTALLED_APPS` on `settings.py`

Comment: updated those info. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for what i've seen, I tries to validade the AdvancedVehicleSearchForm before it runs the migration, try to pass the form related to the vehicle to the vehicle app in the way django can makes the migration first.
I can't help you more for the files you show there sorry.
I hope it helps you somehow

Comment: Thanks for your hint. I commented (# 'django.contrib.admin'), because as errors show it tried to validate the admin and related forms. Then run python3 manage.py migrate. It works like a charm.